# How to dismiss all the dialogs from button click of last opened dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

I am navigating from one dialog to other, likewise I traversed from three dialogs.
Now I want to dismiss all opened dialogs from last dialog click and refresh the fragment.

Is there any simple way to do this?
All helps will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: which dialog are you using ?

Comment: I am using alert dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep references of all dialogs and dismiss them in last dialog click.

```
AlertDialog dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder().build();

AlertDialog dialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder().build();

AlertDialog dialog3 = new AlertDialog.Builder()
             .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked,
                    // dismiss all dialogs
                    dialog1.dismiss();
                    dialog2.dismiss();
                    dialog3.dismiss();
                }
              }).build();
```